# How to delete unused Revolution Slider causing errors from site on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

When I activate the Revolution Slider it comes up as a red warning box on home page of our website: BarbTV.org saying: Revolution Slider with alais home not found and error appears on the mobile size too.

But when I deactivate the Revolution Slider it looks fixed on website but on the mobile app [rev =alias]. It looks like the slider was manually added and the home slider is not being used at all. I would like to delete the whole thing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’ve successfully deactivated the plugin, but the content of your page still has the shortcode to insert a slider. You probably just need to edit the text of the page (or possibly a sidebar widget or the like) to remove the offending text shortcode.